# Why the figure did not change when I change the linewidth argument

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my import statement

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.style
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('classic')
```

I initialized the tuple of fig4 and ax4 as such

```
fig4,ax4 = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize = (10,1.5))
```

and plot the individual graph

```
ax4[0].plot(x,y,color='blue',lw=5,ls='--')
ax4[1].plot(x,z,color='red',lw=3,ls='-')
fig4
```

The problem is that when I run the cell, the result shown does not match the linewidth argument at all like this:
[image]

Another strange problem I also encountered is that, sometimes I run the figure initialization cell and rerun the plotting cell, the result does change, sometimes it does not. And why should I rerun the figure initialization in the first place, the result should change if I change the argument of the method applied to the object.

Comment: Change the color argument will change the result instantly, but other arguments like linewidth,linestyle won't change the result at all.

Comment: Is the behavior any different if you run the initialization and plotting in the same cell?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Yes! If I run them in the same cell, everything seems fine, but why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the plots do not seem to update when split between cells but do when initialization and plotting are in a single cell is because in the former case each time the plotting cell is run the `Line2D` object created by calling `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()` is added to the same `Figure` instance, and in the latter case they are added to a new `Figure` instance. Because the color is being specified the new line cannot be distinguished unless it is wider or the underlying data differs from the previous line.

The simplest solution is to include the initialization in the same cell as the plotting, this is the more conventional scheme and is least likely to produce unexpected behavior like you described in the question.